# liteAccordion with mouseover event

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, horizontal-accordion

I am trying to use 'liteAccordion' jQuery plugin on my website.

This plugin works with click event,but i need it works with mouseover. Does it support mouseover event? and if yes,how can i define it?

Answer (score 1):

you can edit the plugin and replace the two occurrences of `.click` with `.mouseover` in `liteaccordion.jquery.js`

Answer (score 1):

You can just add this line to your javascript.

```
$('#accordion h2').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).click();
});
```

Or you can do what Sotiris advises and modify the plugin directly. It doesn't seem to have native mouseover support.

Answer (score 1):

In v2 you can do

```
$("#myDiv").liteAccordion({
    activateOn: "mouseover"      // or click
});
```